# Payfort missing parameter for SADAD payments

Tags: api, payfort, sadad

I'm integrating Payfort to a shopping cart. Visa and mastercard payments are ok working without issues but I have an issue integrating Sadad through Payfort. I send these parameters

```
<input type="hidden" name="access_code" value="CODE"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100"/>
<input type="hidden" name="command" value="PURCHASE"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="SAR"/>
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="en"/>
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_identifier" value="IDENTIFIER"/>
<input type="hidden" name="merchant_reference" value="ORDER_ID"/>
<input type="hidden" name="payment_option" value="SADAD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="RETURN_URL"/>
<input type="hidden" name="signature" value="GENRATED_SIGNATURE"/>
```

But I et this error 'Missing parameter.' How can I solve this issue?

[update]

Added the email field and now the missing parameter error disappeared but getting this error now "Transaction cannot be processed at this moment"

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer_email" value="EMAIL_ADDRESS"/>
```

Comment: contact payfort for get support

Comment: I want apply PayFort payment gateway in my codeigniter project, please give any suggestion ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to send "sadad_olp" parameter when you dealing with SADADD.